# Secrets of the Javascript Ninja listing 4.8 - how is this property being referenced?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm liking this book, but some of the examples don't fully explain what's going on. Here's an example of a caching function to store a collection of functions:

```
 var store = {
    nextId: 1,                                        //#1
    cache: {},                                        //#2
    add: function(fn) {                               //#3
      if (!fn.id) {                                   //#3
        fn.id = store.nextId++;                       //#3
        return !!(store.cache[fn.id] = fn);           //#3
        // not a fan of the above construct - I think the following is clearer:
        // store.cache[fn.id] = fn;
        // return true;
      }                                               //#3
    }
  };

  function ninja(){}

  assert(store.add(ninja),                            //#4
         "Function was safely added.");               //#4
  console.log('ninja does not have an id property now:',ninja);
  assert(!store.add(ninja),                           //#4
         "But it was only added once.");              //#4
```

Most of this is quite obvious - when store.add(ninja) is called the first time, the fn param doesn't see an id property, so it adds the store.nextId variable as the id property.

What I don't get is how that fn.id property is actually referenced on the next call to store.add(ninja). Whether the function ninja is defined before or after the store variable, logging ninja after the first call to store.add(ninja) doesn't show that ninja now has an id property added by reference. So when passing ninja to store.add the second time, how does add() know that the fn param now has an id property?

Is this some closure magic that the author doesn't explain?

Comment: After the first call to `store.add(ninja)` the ninja function **does** have an id property. See http://jsfiddle.net/m8Vaw/2/ . Edit: you should do `console.dir(ninja)` (not console.log) to see the id property

Comment: Well, I'll be damned - learn something new every day. I'm surprised that console.log doesn't show the id property. Thanks, and now it does make sense. Post your comment as an answer and you'll get points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer-ing my comment, as requested.*

After the first call to `store.add(ninja)` the ninja function **does** have the id property.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Vaw/2)

You should do `console.dir(ninja)` (instead of console.log) to see its properties/prototype methods

Comment: Is this the right way to decide whether or not to store? Should we be assigning properties to a function outside of 'store' and checking the property "id" or should we instead check our cache to see of that function (at least in name) exists?